# Does Statement.Close affect mysql's thread-safe LAST_INSERT_ID in golang?

Tags: mysql, go

I'm using go to insert a new user into the mysql database. Before inserting the user I save some kind of "log-message" in the `msg` table. Both tables (`msg`and `user`) have `auto-increment`. In order to receive the id chosen by auto-increment I use mysql's `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. This should be thread-safe as pointed out in lots of other discussions on stack overflow, because it's bound to a single connection.

I asked myself if `stmt.Close()` after every `stmt.Exec()` will change mysql's behavior (specially thread-safeness) in any way?

```
stmt, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO msg (message) VALUES(?)")
stmt.Exec(msg)
stmt.Close()

stmt, _ = db.Prepare("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
stmt.QueryRow().Scan(&msgid)
stmt.Close()

stmt, _ = db.Prepare("INSERT INTO user (msg_id) VALUES(?)")
stmt.Exec(msgid)
stmt.Close()

stmt, _ = db.Prepare("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
stmt.QueryRow().Scan(&id)
stmt.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the statement, as you're doing, does not close the database connection.  The database connection is what's important for `LAST_INSERT_ID`.  Unless you call [`db.Close()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Close), which closes the underlying connection, your connection remains open.

However, `db` is a *pool* of connections, so there is no guarantee that you'll get the same connection on subsequent queries, regardless of closing the connection, unless you use a transaction.

So in summary, you should do this (adding error handling, of course)

```
tx, _ := db.Begin()

stmt, _ := tx.Prepare("INSERT INTO msg (message) VALUES(?)")
stmt.Exec(msg)
stmt.Close()

stmt, _ = tx.Prepare("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
stmt.QueryRow().Scan(&msgid)
stmt.Close()

_ = tx.Commit()
```

---

However, note that a better way to do this is with [Result.LastInsertId](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Result):

```
stmt, _ := tx.Prepare("INSERT INTO msg (message) VALUES(?)")
res, _ := stmt.Exec(msg)
stmt.Close()

msgid := res.LastInsertId()
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew the first part but didn't know there's something like `transaction`. Thank you! :)